# How to round in Azure batch autoscale formula

Tags: c#, azure, azure-batch

When I commit my formula, Azure complains about calculation errors. I narrowed it down to having a number with decimal places. Here’s my formula:

```
pivot = (0.15*($CurrentDedicated/20)+0.84);
target = $CurrentDedicated*(($CPUPercent.GetSample(TimeInterval_Minute*5)/100)/pivot);
```

Naturally, it complains about not having a sample, so I put in `$CPUPercent.GetSamplePercent(TimeInterval_Minute*0,TimeInterval_Minute*5)` in a ternary expression, but it complains about “evaluation error”. I figure this is happening because I’m trying to provision a fractional number of dedicated machines.

So… How can I round up and down in such an expression?

UPD:

So I found my problem, `$CPUPercent.GetSample` should not be used as a number. Instead, max(), min(), or avg() should be used on it to produce a number. The corrected formula is as follows:

```
samplepercent = $CPUPercent.GetSamplePercent(TimeInterval_Minute*0,TimeInterval_Minute*5);
pivot = (0.15*($CurrentDedicated/20)+0.84);
$TargetDedicated = samplepercent < 0.7 ? 1 : $CurrentDedicated*((avg($CPUPercent.GetSample(TimeInterval_Minute*5))/100)/pivot);
```

Sadly, there is no way to round up or down. The autoscale expressions to not have functions for it and do not have the `%` operator defined (x = x - x%1 and x = x - x%1 + 1 to round down and up respectively). This is sad indeed and may require me to review the above equation to make sure it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Check this thread, they have some examples https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/21161846-6b6b-4e34-85fc-333663414714/autoscaleformula-improvements-needed?forum=azurebatch

Comment: Thanks. Reading this very carefully, I found that my use of CPUPercent.GetSample is incorrect, when I am treating it as a number, but it is, in fact, a vector, so that is the problem, not fractional values.